# How to trigger reports mail on fitnesse slim test runs?

Tags: continuous-integration, fitnesse, fitnesse-slim, email-notifications, anthill

We are using Fitnesse slim in our project. As of now we were executing the fitnesse tests (slim) from wiki page and we were checking the results manually from wiki itself.

Now, we are planning to implement CI for our project. So, is there a way to integrate fitnesse slim with AnthilPro (CI tool) and can run fitnesse tests / suits automatically and send the execution results to specified set of email IDs ?

Kindly help me out. I know that, many have already implemented this. But, i am not getting the exact info i am looking for anywhere.

Thank you,
Chethan

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with anthillpro, but I run fitnesse test using their junit runner on teamcity and Jenkins. 
This produces test results those ci tools pick up automatically, and html reports for people to see the test details.
Mailing people based on build outcome is a standard feature of the tools. I assume for anthill also.

Would that work for you?

[My fitnesse baseline project](https://github.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures) contains a maven setup to run a fitnesse suite with a single maven call: `mvn clean test-compile failsafe:integration-test`. 
I assume that making a job the checks out a project, executes a maven call and then e-mails based on test outcome is just as simple to setup in anthill as in other ci tools.

Comment: Thanks Fried for your response. Could you please elaborate how you are integrating your fitnesse suits/tests with junit runner? I am new to this.                                                                                                                Thank you.

Comment: Do you have some experience adding unit tests to a Java project? The basic approach is to add a Java class to my project's unit tests which has annotations to indicate which FitNesse suite should be run, like https://github.com/unclebob/fitnesse/blob/master/test/fitnesse/junit/FitNesseRunnerTest.java.

Comment: Yes Fried, i am aware of unit tests written to do the code coverage. But, in our project we are having our actual prodect code with junits as a separate project, fixture code (java) as a separate project and fitnesse as a separate project. So, we are struggling to integrate all.

Comment: How is your fitnesse project structured? I usually make that a maven project too.

Comment: It is a maven project. The pom file for our fixture code project and for the Fitnesse project are same. 

Below is the background of our project.

* Our project is in the UNIX system.
*   We have kept our fixture class files in the Unix system.
* In the Fitnesse page we are providing the path of the .class files and the required jar files path.
*   So, when we run a Fitnesse test/suite. It refers the .class files path and the jars for execution.

Now, we want to setup CI for this project as I mentioned above.

Comment: In that case adding the junit test to run the fitnesse suite is just a matter of adding a class to test source directory of the project. In my project I went one step further by classifying the fitnesse tests as integration tests (using maven's failsafe plugin). Check out my project's pom on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks Fried for the details. I am able to run the fitnesse as part of maven build by using the 'maven-antrun-plugin' , now I am stuck with below problem. Any suggestion ? If you have nay please provide them in the below link. Thank you.                                                                                                         http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39053436/how-to-setup-multiple-fitnesse-suites-in-pom-file-using-maven-antrun-plugin-an