# How to setup multiple fitnesse suites in pom file using maven-antrun-plugin ? and how to call the specific suite run among the configured suits?

Tags: maven, ant, fitnesse, maven-antrun-plugin

I am able to run the `FitNesse suite` from maven build with the following setup.

```
<properties>
    <fitnesse.version>20160618</fitnesse.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.fitnesse</groupId>
        <artifactId>fitnesse</artifactId>
        <version>${fitnesse.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.fitnesse.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-classpath-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-fitnesse-integration</id>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <echo taskname="fitnesse" message="Starting FitNesse..." />
                            <java classname="fitnesseMain.FitNesseMain" classpathref="maven.runtime.classpath"
                                fork="true" failonerror="true">
                                <jvmarg value="-Xmx1024m" />
                                <arg line="-p 9000" />
                                <arg line="-c FrontPage.TestSuite?suite&amp;amp;format=text" />
                                <arg line="-e 0" />
                                <!-- <arg line="-d ." /> -->
                            </java>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I am running the  `FitNesse suite` using the below command.

```
mvn clean install
```

Now I want to configure execution of multiple  `FitNesse suites` as part of `pom.xml` and want to run specific suite as part of maven build.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to configure multiple suites to be run:

- Add multiple `execution` elements to your pom (inside the `executions` element you already have) one per suite, each with a unique `id`
- Place all suites you want to run under a shared parent suite (and run the parent suite). You can also use [symbolic links](http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.FitNesseWiki.SymbolicLinks) to achieve this.
- Create a [suite query page](http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.FullReferenceGuide.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests.TestSuites.SuiteQuery) to indicate which suites should be run (and run that page).
- Create a [suite cross reference page](http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.FullReferenceGuide.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests.TestSuites.CrossReferenceSuites) and run that
- Give all suites the same tag and use [filters](http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.FullReferenceGuide.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests.TestSuites.TagsAndFilters) to select all suites to run based on the tag

P.S. Why are you using the antrun plugin instead of [maven-exec](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html)?